# Hyper-v takes a long time to create snapshots

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, windows-server-2012, snapshot

I'm not sure when, but I've noticed as of recently, whenever I go to make a snapshot of certain machines, it hangs at 2% for a good while and then eventually finishes (fairly quickly, actually). I don't believe I noticed it before. Is it waiting for something else to finish?

I've also noticed that sometimes during a reboot of the guest machine, it takes an equal amount of time to stop the guest before rebooting.

I've already rebooted the host. I'm running Windows server 2012. Thanks.

Comment: This could be due to a lot of factors. Size of the vhd having a snapshot taken, the size of the snapshot tree, resources (storage, CPU, memory) on the host server. Can you give a little more info on those things?

Comment: The VHDX files are fairly small linux distros. Usually, it's pretty quick. It just seems to now have this delay before it actually creates it (hanging at 2% for a bit). After that, it's quick.

Comment: BTW, the merge process actually is quicker than the snapshot right now.

Comment: Here's my two cents: When creating a snapshot (similarly when exporting a VM) the snapshot process has to create the avhd file, this is the longest part of the process and is why you see the snapshot process "hang" and then finish quickly. When it seems to be "hanging" it's actually creating the avhd. Merging the snapshot is quicker because only the differences are merged back into the VM.